# Publisher not responding to last email

Tags: publishing, publisher

I sent a book proposal to a publisher back in June 2020. The publisher responded that they liked the book and it went through successfully the first round of review. There is a second round of review to which the book has been ‘in limbo’ for several months. I have reached out to the publisher for a status via two emails and have yet to receive a response. What should I do so that I can find out the status of my book proposal? Note: this book is a technical book.

UPDATE: publisher finally responded almost a year later and said the book would not be published - no further detailed feedback.

Comment: Most publishers have guidelines on their websites about how long things are likely to take (generally between 'really' long and 'ridiculously' long). What do these say? Otherwise, do you know anyone who has published with the publisher? Ask them what their experience with the company is.

Comment: The publisher’s website unfortunately has no such information.  And I do not know anyone who has used this publisher.  But thank you for your input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> There is a second round of review to which the book has been ‘in limbo’ for several months.

It's my understanding many publishers have a workflow of about 1 year. Meaning they take on a fixed number of books (projects is also a good word) and after that capacity is exhausted everything gets scheduled for next year. Many writers have said the publisher contacted them stating: "We like your book and accept publishing it, but now you'll have to wait for next year's season."

Assuming the publisher in question has professionalism, they're unlikely to drop the project without letting you know. It's probably the case that they're in between evaluations and have a policy of not returning contacts or giving feedback in this phase (if the book's evaluation advanced nothing whatsoever, what would they say?)

I've heard some writers say in interviews that they got the contact you are expecting and when they heard the estimate of the waiting time they decided to go find another publisher, or publish the book themselves...

> What should I do so that I can find out the status of my book proposal?

Calling by phone is obviously the next step.

Comment: It hadn’t occurred to me that they have/had all their books due for publishing already set for this year and (perhaps) mine was slated for next year (although you would think they would say something to that affect in an email).

Answer (score 2):

Probably, the quickest way to find out what is going on is to phone the editor at the publisher who is responsible for your book.